# Why drag and drop stopped working in chrome: bug (not very likely) or am I missing something (very likely)?

Tags: java, testing, drag-and-drop, webdriver, automated-tests

webdriver version is 2.25, chromedriver is version 23.0, chrome  browser is up to date (currently 21.0.180.89)

Application under test is GWT application and I have test cases that perform drag and drop.
For some reason drag and drop functionality has stopped working in Chrome, while IE and Firefox are working ok. 
Below is code that fails (unfortunately I cannot provide public access to the app. Let me know if you need more details):

```
public void dragPropertyToCustomSection(String propertyName) {
    WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.id(propertyName));;
    WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.drop-target"));
    (new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(source, target).build().perform();
    clickSaveChangesButton();
}
```

I’ve tried everything I knew and still cannot get it to work in Chrome.  Any ideas why this is not working?

Is this the same as http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4455 ?

Comment: I think it may be simply something with webdriver / chrome version and there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: Are you trying to drag and drop across frames?